# Remove whitespaces in XML string

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization, python-2.6, elementtree

How can I remove the whitespaces and line breaks in an XML string in Python 2.6? I tried the following packages:

etree: This snippet keeps the original whitespaces:

```
xmlStr = '''<root>
    <head></head>
    <content></content>
</root>'''

xmlElement = xml.etree.ElementTree.XML(xmlStr)
xmlStr = xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(xmlElement, 'UTF-8')
print xmlStr
```

I can not use Python 2.7 which would provide the `method` parameter.

minidom: just the same:

```
xmlDocument = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlStr)
xmlStr = xmlDocument.toprettyxml(indent='', newl='', encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: This may help using lxml to remove all blank lines and white-spaces from text node http://stackoverflow.com/a/19396130/973699

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), where you can set a parser option to ignore white space between elements:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
>>> xml_str = '''<root>
>>>     <head></head>
>>>     <content></content>
>>> </root>'''
>>> elem = etree.XML(xml_str, parser=parser)
>>> print etree.tostring(elem)
<root><head/><content/></root>
```

This will probably be enough for your needs, but some warnings to be on the safe side:

This will just remove whitespace nodes between elements, and try not to remove whitespace nodes inside elements with mixed content:

```
>>> elem = etree.XML('<p> spam <a>ham</a> <a>eggs</a></p>', parser=parser)
>>> print etree.tostring(elem)
<p> spam <a>ham</a> <a>eggs</a></p>
```

Leading or trailing whitespace from textnodes will not be removed. It will however still in some circumstances remove whitespace nodes from mixed content: if the parser has not encountered non-whitespace nodes at that level yet.

```
>>> elem = etree.XML('<p><a> ham</a> <a>eggs</a></p>', parser=parser)
>>> print etree.tostring(elem)
<p><a> ham</a><a>eggs</a></p>
```

If you don't want that, you can use `xml:space="preserve"`, which will be respected. Another option would be using a dtd and use `etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True)`, where the parser will use the dtd to determine which whitespace nodes are significant or not.

Other than that, you will have to write your own code to remove the whitespace you don't want (iterating descendants, and where appropriate, set `.text` and `.tail` properties that contain only whitespace to `None` or empty string)

Comment: I have found that, as pointed out by @Steven, some elements containing only whitespaces are not cleaned. I have used a regex to do so after the call to `etree.tostring`: `re.sub(r'>\s+<', '><', xml_str)`

Comment: Please replace `etree.XML(xml_str, parser=p)` with `etree.XML(xml_str, parser=parser)` in first snippet.

Comment: If you can use Python 3.9, there's a new function [xml.etree.ElementTree.indent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent) that can also help address this without the need for any lxml dependencies.

Answer (score 33):

Here's something quick I came up with because I didn't want to use lxml:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Node

def remove_blanks(node):
    for x in node.childNodes:
        if x.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:
            if x.nodeValue:
                x.nodeValue = x.nodeValue.strip()
        elif x.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            remove_blanks(x)

xml = minidom.parse('file.xml')
remove_blanks(xml)
xml.normalize()
with file('file.xml', 'w') as result:
    result.write(xml.toprettyxml(indent = '  '))
```

Which I really only needed to re-indent the XML file with otherwise broken indentation. It doesn't respect the `preserve` directive, but, honestly, so do so many other software dealing with XMLs, that it's rather a funny requirement :) Also, you'd be able to easily add that sort of functionality to the code above (just check for `space` attribute, and don't recure if its value is 'preserve'.)

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't want to add lxml to my project and this worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: Awesome ! This really helped

Comment: This is a great answer with no external dependencies!

Answer (score 7):

Whitespace is significant within an XML document. Using whitespace for indentation is a poor use of XML, as it introduces significant data where there really is none -- and sadly, this is the norm. Any programmatic approach you take to stripping out whitespace will be, at best, a guess - you need better knowledge of what the XML is conveying to properly remove whitespace, without stepping on some piece of data's toes.

Comment: Sometimes it is, sometimes it's not. Specifically, if there's a DTD or Schema it's probably not significant. See discussion at 
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlStr = xmlDocument.toprettyxml(indent='\t', newl='\n', encoding='UTF-8')
fix = re.compile(r'((?<=>)(\n[\t]*)(?=[^<\t]))|(?<=[^>\t])(\n[\t]*)(?=<)')
newXmlStr = re.sub(fix, '', xmlStr )
```

from [this source](http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/xml-dom-minidom-toprettyxml-and-silly-whitespace/)

Comment: what is re? For me re is not defined

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that bothers me about xml.dom.minidom's toprettyxml() is that it adds blank lines.  I don't seem to get the split components, so I just wrote a simple function to remove the blank lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xml.dom.minidom

# toprettyxml() without the blank lines
def prettyPrint(x):
    for line in x.toprettyxml().split('\n'):
        if not line.strip() == '':
            print line

xml_string = "<monty>\n<example>something</example>\n<python>parrot</python>\n</monty>"

# parse XML
x = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)

# clean
prettyPrint(x)
```

And this is what the code outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<monty>
        <example>something</example>
        <python>parrot</python>
</monty>
```

If I use toprettyxml() by itself, i.e. print(toprettyxml(x)), it adds unnecessary blank lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<monty>


        <example>something</example>


        <python>parrot</python>


</monty>
```

Answer (score -1):

A little clumsy solution **without lxml** :-)

```
data = """<root>

    <head></head>    <content></content>

</root>"""

data3 = []
data2 = data.split('\n')
for x in data2:
    y = x.strip()
    if y: data3.append(y)
data4 = ''.join(data3)
data5 = data4.replace("  ","").replace("> <","><")

print data5

Output: <root><head></head><content></content></root>
```

Answer (score -1):

If whitespace in "non-leaf" nodes is what we're trying to remove then the following function will do it (recursively if specified):

```
from xml.dom import Node

def stripNode(node, recurse=False):
    nodesToRemove = []
    nodeToBeStripped = False

    for childNode in node.childNodes:
        # list empty text nodes (to remove if any should be)
        if (childNode.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE and childNode.nodeValue.strip() == ""):
            nodesToRemove.append(childNode)

        # only remove empty text nodes if not a leaf node (i.e. a child element exists)
        if childNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            nodeToBeStripped = True

    # remove flagged text nodes
    if nodeToBeStripped:
        for childNode in nodesToRemove:
            node.removeChild(childNode)

    # recurse if specified
    if recurse:
        for childNode in node.childNodes:
            stripNode(childNode, True)
```

However, Thanatos is correct. Whitespace can represent data in XML so use with caution.

Answer (score -3):

```
xmlStr = ' '.join(xmlStr.split()))
```

This puts all text in one line replacing multiple white space with single blank.

```
xmlStr = ''.join(xmlStr.split()))
```

This would remove completely space including the spaces inside the text and **can not be used.**

The first form could be used with risk (but that you request), for the input you gave:

```
xmlStr = '''<root>
    <head></head>
    <content></content>
</root>'''
xmlStr = ' '.join(xmlStr.split())
print xmlStr
""" Output:
<root> <head></head> <content></content> </root>
"""
```

This would be valid xml. It would need to be though checked with some kind of xml checker maybe. Are you by the way sure you want XML? Have you read the article:
[Python Is Not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)

Comment: -1 Your suggestion will trash anything like `"""<v xml:space="preserve">\t\tfoo</v>"""`

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with John. This doesn't preserve the XML syntax at all.