# Python script to remove all comments from XML file

Tags: python, xml, dom, xpath

I am trying to build a python script that will take in an XML document and remove all of the comment blocks from it.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(file)
commentElements = tree.findall('//comment()')

for element in commentElements:
    element.parentNode.remove(element)
```

Doing this yields a weird error from python: "KeyError: '()'

I know there are ways to easily edit the file using other methods ( like sed ), but I have to do it in a python script.

Comment: Could you maybe add a little example XML document?

Comment: `'//comment()'` does not seem to be a valid search path format and is causing the KeyError. Can you please include that XML sample and expand on the pattern you are trying to catch?

Comment: `comment()` is an XPath node test that is not supported by ElementTree. Try [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath), which has full support for XPath 1.0.

Comment: lxml also implements the etree interface, AFAIK

Answer (score 12):

`comment()` is an XPath node test that is not supported by ElementTree.

You can use `comment()` with **[lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html)**. This library is quite similar to ElementTree and it has full support for XPath 1.0.

Here is how you can remove comments with lxml:

```python
from lxml import etree

XML = """<root>
  <!-- COMMENT 1 -->
  <x>TEXT 1</x>
  <y>TEXT 2 <!-- COMMENT 2 --></y>
</root>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(XML)

comments = tree.xpath('//comment()')

for c in comments:
    p = c.getparent()
    p.remove(c)

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <x>TEXT 1</x>
  <y>TEXT 2 </y>
</root>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use strip_tags() from lxml.etree

```
from lxml import etree
XML = """<root>
  <!-- COMMENT 1 -->
  <x>TEXT 1</x>
  <y>TEXT 2 <!-- COMMENT 2 --></y>
  </root>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(XML)
print etree.tostring(tree)
etree.strip_tags(tree,etree.Comment)
print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Output:

```
<root>
<!-- COMMENT 1 -->
<x>TEXT 1</x>
<y>TEXT 2 <!-- COMMENT 2 --></y>
</root>
<root>

<x>TEXT 1</x>
<y>TEXT 2 </y>
</root>
```

Answer (score 6):

The same as

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3317008/1458574

```
from lxml import etree
import sys

XML = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
parser =  etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)
tree= etree.fromstring(XML, parser = parser)
print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: `remove_comments=True` works fine, but it's not used in the linked answer. So why do you say that it is "the same"?

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I implemented using minidom:

```
 def removeCommentNodes(self):
        for tag in self.dom.getElementsByTagName("*"):
            for n in tag.childNodes:
                if n.nodeType is dom.Node.COMMENT_NODE:
                    n.parentNode.removeChild(n)
```

In practice I first retrieve all the tags in the xml, then for each tag I look for comment nodes and if found I remove them. (self.dom is a reference to the parsed xml)