# How to remove html comments with python's lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I've a large set of html documents and I need to remove the certain html elements and html comments also.

I've used `strip_elements()` for removing specific html elements. Can it be used to remove the **html comments** enclosed within `<!--` and `-->`, or should I need to use some other method?

Sample:

```
<div class=\"detail_text\" id=\"detikdetailtext\">\n\t\t\t<!-- s:pic detail -->\n\t\t\t<!-- S:read image orientation if potrait load this -->\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!-- E:read image orientation if potrait load this -->\n\t\t\t<!-- e:pic detail -->\n\n\t\t\t<b>Jakarta<\/b> - Fraksi Golkar setuju dengan inisiasi Fraksi PDIP yang menginginkan revisi UU MD3 terkait formasi pimpinan DPR. Golkar pun mengusulkan agar ada penambahan kursi pimpinan.<br>
```

Comment: post sample html code.

Comment: Sample:
`<div class=\"detail_text\" id=\"detikdetailtext\">\n\t\t\t<!-- s:pic detail -->\n\t\t\t<!-- S:read image orientation if potrait load this -->\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!-- E:read image orientation if potrait load this -->\n\t\t\t<!-- e:pic detail -->\n\n\t\t\t<b>Jakarta<\/b> - Fraksi Golkar setuju dengan inisiasi Fraksi PDIP yang menginginkan revisi UU MD3 terkait formasi pimpinan DPR. Golkar pun mengusulkan agar ada penambahan kursi pimpinan.<br>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10437575/965002

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use regex, there is a pattern can be used to match all comment.

```
import re
html = '''<div class=\"detail_text\" id=\"detikdetailtext\">\n\t\t\t<!-- s:pic detail -->\n\t\t\t<!-- S:read image orientation if potrait load this -->\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!-- E:read image orientation if potrait load this -->\n\t\t\t<!-- e:pic detail -->\n\n\t\t\t<b>Jakarta<\/b> - Fraksi Golkar setuju dengan inisiasi Fraksi PDIP yang menginginkan revisi UU MD3 terkait formasi pimpinan DPR. Golkar pun mengusulkan agar ada penambahan kursi pimpinan.<br>'''
re.sub(r'<!--.+?-->', '', html)
```

out:

```
'<div class="detail_text" id="detikdetailtext">\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t<b>Jakarta<\\/b> - Fraksi Golkar setuju dengan inisiasi Fraksi PDIP yang menginginkan revisi UU MD3 terkait formasi pimpinan DPR. Golkar pun mengusulkan agar ada penambahan kursi pimpinan.<br>'
```