# python remove comments on the xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

The xml file containe the returns:

```
<!-- This xml is designed for testing --> 
<returns>
    <obs>0.008053735</obs>
    <obs>0.004752907</obs>
    <obs>0.004682267</obs>
    <obs>0.003029358</obs>
</returns>
```

Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np

r=[]
def LoadReturn():
  try:
    treexml = ET.parse('./sample_data/returns.xml')
    root = treexml.getroot()
    for ts in root:
      r.append(ts.text)    
  except:
    print("Failed to parse xml from response (%s)" % traceback.format_exc())
  return r
```

I want to delete the comment line of the XML. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you,
L

Comment: So you want to modify the file?

Comment: Yes I want to modify the content of the xml file.

Comment: see if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517123/10407557

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?