# Python how to strip white-spaces from xml text nodes

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I have a xml file as follows

```
<Person>
<name>

 My Name

</name>
<Address>My Address</Address>
</Person>
```

The  tag has extra new lines, Is there any quick Pythonic way to trim this and generate a new xml.

I found this but it trims only which are between tags not the value
https://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2010/04/remove-insignificant-whitespace-from-xml-string-with-python/

**Update 1 - Handle following xml which has tail spaces in `<name>` tag**

```
<Person>
<name>

 My Name<shortname>My</short>

</name>
<Address>My Address</Address>
</Person>
```

Accepted answer handle above both kind of xml's

**Update 2 - I have posted my version in answer below, I am using it to remove all kind of whitespaces and generate pretty xml in file with xml encodings**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19396130/973699

Comment: You may have more success with JSON

Comment: @Temere this is being used by other app and before it comes to my python program for validation

Comment: Your additional example (on which the accepted answer does not work) is not well-formed. Be careful with the start- and end tags. And btw, you are "moving the goalposts". I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: @mzjn Yes, I could have asked a different questions, but I thought it is related, so it will great if best solution exist in this thread itself. I have posted my version in answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19396130/973699

Comment: @mzjn I just read this, I will take care next time . http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153360/how-to-avoid-repositioning-of-goalposts-when-using-improve-details-bounty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `lxml` you can iterate over all elements and check if it has text to `strip()`:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('xmlfile')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter('*'):
    if elem.text is not None:
        elem.text = elem.text.strip()

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

It yields:

```
<Person><name>My Name</name>
<Address>My Address</Address>
</Person>
```

---

**UPDATE** to strip `tail` text too:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('xmlfile')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter('*'):
    if elem.text is not None:
        elem.text = elem.text.strip()
    if elem.tail is not None:
        elem.tail = elem.tail.strip()

print(etree.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True))
```

Comment: Perfect it worked, the only issue is that it doesn't preserve the xml version tag like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: @DevC: Your data didn't include it. You can add it when printing: `print(etree.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True))`

Comment: No, the actual xml file which I am trying have this but the final result doesn't show this. I don't want to hard code it as it may be changed.

Comment: I am keeping you answer accepted, but it doesn't work in above update condition

Comment: @DevC: This mixed-content of an element surrounded with text in both sides, can be extracted with the `tail` property that can be stripped too. I've updated the answer to adapt to your new case.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer given by Birei using lxml does the job perfectly, but I wanted to trim all kind of white/blank space, blank lines and regenerate pretty xml in a xml file.

Following code did what I wanted

```
from lxml import etree

#discard strings which are entirely white spaces
myparser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

root = etree.parse('xmlfile',myparser)

#from Birei's answer 
for elem in root.iter('*'):
    if elem.text is not None:
        elem.text = elem.text.strip()
    if elem.tail is not None:
        elem.tail = elem.tail.strip()

#write the xml file with pretty print and xml encoding
root.write('xmlfile', pretty_print=True, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do xml parsing for this one way or another, so maybe use `xml.sax` and copy to the output stream at each event (skipping `ignorableWhitespace`), and add tag markers as needed. Check the sample code here http://www.knowthytools.com/2010/03/sax-parsing-with-python.html.

Comment: It would've really helped if you showed an example. Can't get to the link from work, and it's the only 2.3-compatible standard library answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). Do traverse all elements and for each one that contains some text, replace it with its stripped version:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('xmlfile', 'r'), 'xml')

for elem in soup.find_all():
    if elem.string is not None:
        elem.string = elem.string.strip()

print(soup)
```

Assuming `xmlfile` with the content provided in the question, it yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person>
<name>My Name</name>
<Address>My Address</Address>
</Person>
```

Comment: I'm assuming BeautifulSoup would abstract some details of xml, so he's better dealing with lxml or other parser directly to have a general solution, unless his xml is controlled.

Comment: @Birei yes as mentioned by Basel I am looking for doing it with xml parser like lxml/etree or minidom

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with an older version of Python (2.3), and I'm currently stuck with the standard library. To show an answer that's greatly backwards compatible, I've written this with [`xml.dom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html) and [`xml.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) functions.

```
import codecs
from xml.dom import minidom

# Read in the file to a DOM data structure.
original_document = minidom.parse("original_document.xml")

# Open a UTF-8 encoded file, because it's fairly standard for XML.
stripped_file = codecs.open("stripped_document.xml", "w", encoding="utf8")

# Tell minidom to format the child text nodes without any extra whitespace.
original_document.writexml(stripped_file, indent="", addindent="", newl="")

stripped_file.close()
```

While it's not `BeautifulSoup`, this solution is pretty elegant and uses the full force of the lower-level API. Note that the actual formatting is just one line :)

Documentation of API calls used here:

- [`minidom.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parse)
- [`minidom.Node.writexml`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.writexml)
- [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open)