# Python 2.7 - sort elements by the value of given subelement

Tags: xml, python-2.7, sorting

I have an xml, simplified version is below. I need to sort *variable* elements by *name* subelements.

```
<task>
  <name>tsk name</name>
  <id>123</id>
  <agent />
  <variable>
    <name>var 687</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <chld>hgkj</chld>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <name>var 246</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <chld>khgkj</chld>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <name>var 296</name>
    <value>9</value>
    <chld>fjhgf</chld>
  </variable>
</task>
```

I need to have *variable* element with *name* subelement with value 246 first, *variable* element with *name* subelement with value 296 second and *variable* element with *name* subelement with value 687 last.
I know how to sort elements but I do not know how to sort them by certain subelements. I also have no attributes to sort the variable elements by. Would anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting XML in python etree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338817/sorting-xml-in-python-etree)

Comment: I saw the question and its solution, but I think this is different case. I have no attributes to sort variable elements by. I need to sort them by name subelement.