# Apply node specific sort criteria in a single XML document

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, sorting, elementtree

I'm new to Python programming and trying to re-arrange tags in an XML document with different sort orders per node.

The issue is the XML file doesn't have uniform structure, like some nodes are 1-level deep, and some has data up to 4-level.

So far, I referred several StackOverflow posts with similar question, checked other blog posts and also referred **XMLTree** documentation as well. But, I think I'm missing something. I'm trying to solve using `ElementTree` from `xml.etree` module, and haven't checked the `lxml` module yet.

**XML Snippet:**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?org schema-ver='8.6' ?>
<org>
  <setup>
    <app-host>example.com</app-host>
    <app-port>80</app-port>
    <alternateNames>
      <hostname>b.example.com</hostname>
      <hostname>a.example.com</hostname>
      <hostname>c.example.com</hostname>
    </alternateNames>
    <departments>
      <departmentNames>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>physics</name>
          </department>
          <available>false</available>
        </departmentName>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>math</name>
          </department>
          <available>true</available>
        </departmentName>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>biology</name>
          </department>
          <available>false</available>
        </departmentName>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>chemistry</name>
          </department>
          <available>false</available>
        </departmentName>
      </departmentNames>
    </departments>
  </setup>
  <affiliation>
    <sisterCollege>
        <name>C</name>
    </sisterCollege>
    <sisterCollege>
        <name>A</name>
    </sisterCollege>
    <sisterCollege>
        <name>B</name>
    </sisterCollege>
  </affiliation>
  <courseMaterials>
    <courses/>
  </courseMaterials>
</org>
```

**Expected Output:**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?org schema-ver='8.6' ?>
<org>
  <setup>
    <app-host>example.com</app-host>
    <app-port>80</app-port>
    <alternateNames>
      <!-- ASC order -->
      <hostname>a.example.com</hostname>
      <hostname>b.example.com< /hostname>
      <hostname>c.example.com</hostname>
    </alternateNames>
    <departments>
      <!-- DESC order using departmentNames/departmentName/department/name -->
      <departmentNames>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>physics</name>
          </department>
          <available>false</available>
        </departmentName>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>math</name>
          </department>
          <available>true</available>
        </departmentName>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>chemistry</name>
          </department>
          <available>false</available>
        </departmentName>
        <departmentName>
          <department>
            <name>biology</name>
          </department>
          <available>false</available>
        </departmentName>
      </departmentNames>
    </departments>
  </setup>
  <affiliation>
    <!-- No sort required -->
    <sisterCollege>
        <name>C</name>
    </sisterCollege>
    <sisterCollege>
        <name>A</name>
    </sisterCollege>
    <sisterCollege>
        <name>B</name>
    </sisterCollege>
  </affiliation>
  <courseMaterials>
    <courses/>
  </courseMaterials>
</org>
```

The following code I tried so far:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338817/sorting-xml-in-python-etree
# for org/setup/alternateNames node
def sortchildrenby(parent):
    parent[:] = sorted(parent, key=lambda child: child.text)
    # print(ET.dump(parent))

def sortchildrenby2(parent2):
    # approach-1: Didn't work
    # parent2[:] = sorted(parent, key=lambda child:
    #   child.find('departmentNames').find('departmentName').find('department').find('name').text)
    
    # approach-2: sort nested elements (didn't work)
    # for c1 in parent2:
    #   for c2 in c1:
    #     for c3 in c2:
    #       for c4 in c3:
    #         c4[:] = sorted(c4, key=lambda child: child.text)

    #print(ET.dump(parent2))

    # approach-3: didn't work either    
    # data = []
    # for elem in parent2.findall('department'):
    #   key = elem.findtext('name')
    #   # key = key.strip()
    #   data.append((key, elem))
    # data.sort()
    # parent2[:] = [item[1] for item in data]
    print(ET.dump(parent2))
    

tree = ET.parse('temp.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

setup = root.find('setup')
alternateNames = setup.find('alternateNames')

# seems working
sort_alternateNames = sortchildrenby(alternateNames)
departments  = setup.find('departments')

sort_departments = sortchildrenby2(departments)

print('1-asc: ' + ET.dump(alternateNames)) # seems working for a single node
print('2-desc' + ET.dump(sort_departments)) # prints same as input

ET.tostring(tree)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the wanted sorting. The `hostname` children of `alternateNames` are sorted by their content. The `departmentName` children of `departmentNames` are sorted by the content of `departmentName/department/name`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
tree = ET.parse('temp.xml')
 
# Sort the children of alternateNames
alt_names = tree.find(".//alternateNames")
alt_names[:] = sorted(alt_names, key=lambda child: child.text)
 
# Sort the children of departmentNames (descending)
dep_names = tree.find(".//departmentNames")
dep_names[:] = sorted(dep_names, 
                      key=lambda child: child.findtext("department/name"), 
                      reverse=True)
```