# Shortening HTML files

Tags: python, html

Is there a library (preferably a Python one) that shortens an HTML page? By that I mean that it will produce a possibly smaller (in terms of number of characters, including line breaks <- think about the length of a string) HTML page that is rendered exactly the same as the original one?

For instance:

```
<b>
    Silly example
</b>
```

could be changed to:

```
<b>Silly example</b>
```

and the final result would be the same:

**Silly example**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove whitespaces in XML string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310614/remove-whitespaces-in-xml-string)

Comment: The difference is that I am talking about HTML and not XML...

Comment: Read the answers. Most of them deal with HTML. If you know that your HTML is not well-formed, then you can use BeautifulSoup or even the HTMLParser class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/) to prettify (not minify) HTML or XML code in Python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('file.html')
prettified = soup.prettify(encoding="utf8")
```

For minifying HTML in Python you can use [htmlmin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/htmlmin). More parameters for `htmlmin.minify` can be found in the [documentation](https://htmlmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html).

```
import htmlmin

with open('file.html', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    minified = htmlmin.minify(content, remove_empty_space=True)
```

Comment: Doesn't "prettify" do the exact opposite of what I want? I think "prettify" will make it longer (and not sorter). Am I right?

Comment: This answer is wrong. OP wants to compress the HTML.

Comment: Also, "prettify" does not seem to remove line breaks. On the contrary, it will add them and possibly make my files longer...

Comment: Please use htmlmin (and other minifiers) with care, I had a case where it moved the title tag from head into body...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [htmlmin](https://htmlmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```
import htmlmin

input_html = '<b>\n\tSilly example\n</b>'

minified_html = htmlmin.minify(input_html)

print(input_html)

# <b>
#   Silly example
# </b>


print(minified_html)

# <b> Silly example </b>
```