# Child nodes of XML nodes always have extra 0th node

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am trying to parse the following XML node using Python's `minidom`.

```
<!-- Mapping of subjects -->
<root>
    <English>
       <key name = "Eng"></key>
    </English>
    <Maths>
        <key name = "Mathematics"></key>
    </Maths>
    <SocialScience>
      <key name = "Social"></key>
      <key name = "Scocial"></key>
    </SocialScience>
    <NameoftheStudent>
        <key name="Student's Name"></key>
        <key name = "StudentName"></key>
    </NameoftheStudent>
</root>
```

Following is the code for processing above XML:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('./templates/dictionary.xml')
root = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('root')
for nodes in root:
    for node in nodes.childNodes:
        for x in node.childNodes:
            print "hello"
```

What I have realized is that whenever I am retrieving child nodes, it is giving me one extra child node.

Comment: Have you looked at the objects? Do you get line break text nodes, e.g. `<DOM Text node "u'\n    '">`?

Comment: I have put debugger and yes I am getting  <DOM Text node "u'\n '">.

Comment: What should I not put line break?

Comment: Erm... what? Could you clarify exactly what the problem is? Can't you just ignore irrelevant nodes?

Comment: My question is that why is line break coming as childnode and how can ignore it?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16919069/8747).