# How to get concatenated child text nodes in lxml

Tags: xpath, lxml, lxml.html

This is the `HTML` sample:

```
<div class="wpb_text_column">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://somepage1.com">First text part </a></p>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://somepage2.com">Second text part </a></p>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://somepage3.com">Third text part</a></p>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="wpb_text_column">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://somepage4.com">First text part </a></p>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://somepage5.com">Second text part</a></p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

With below code

```
tree = html.fromstring(html_sample)
tree.xpath('//div[@class="wpb_text_column"]/div[@class="wpb_wrapper"]/p/a/text()')
```

I can get list of text values

```
['First text part ', 'Second text part ', 'Third text part', 'First text part ', 'Second text part']
```

However, I want to get all values from each `div` as single string like

```
['First text part Second text part Third text part', 'First text part Second text part']
```

and

```
//div[@class="wpb_text_column"]/div[@class="wpb_wrapper"]/normalize-space()
```

seem to be [exact `XPath` to solve the problem](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22wpb_text_column%22%3E%0A%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22wpb_wrapper%22%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsomepage1.com%22%3EFirst%20text%20part%20%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsomepage2.com%22%3ESecond%20text%20part%20%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsomepage3.com%22%3EThird%20text%20part%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22wpb_text_column%22%3E%0A%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22wpb_wrapper%22%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsomepage4.com%22%3EFirst%20text%20part%20%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsomepage5.com%22%3ESecond%20text%20part%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv[%40class%3D%22wpb_text_column%22]%2Fdiv[%40class%3D%22wpb_wrapper%22]%2Fnormalize-space()&=&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2), but `lxml` doesn't support `/normalize-space()` syntax:

> lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

So how to get desired output in `lxml`?

Comment: There seems to be an option in lxml parser to ignore white space while parsing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310614/remove-whitespaces-in-xml-string

Comment: Using `tree = html.fromstring(html_sample, parser=etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))` gives an error `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with below code:

```
[" ".join(string.text_content().split()) for string in tree.xpath('//div[@class="wpb_text_column"]/div[@class="wpb_wrapper"]')]
```