# python script to strip white spaces

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm fairly new to python looking for an help! on this I have this string which has a xml content. I need to strip white spaces in between different tags.

```
<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>
```

afterwards it looks like:

```
<SIMPLE_RETURN><RESPONSE><DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME><CODE>2014</CODE><TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT></RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>
```

Appreciated if anyone can help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove whitespaces in XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310614/remove-whitespaces-in-xml-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **regex**.

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>"""
print(re.sub("([\>])\s+([\<])", "\g<1>\g<2>", s))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex, you could do this: (It also looks easier to me for someone new to understand how it works, but I am not aware if this is the best way to do it)

```
my_str = '<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>'
new_str = ''
for character in my_str:
    if character != ' ':
        new_str = new_str + character
```

And then, if you do:

```
print(new_str)
```

the output is:

```
'<SIMPLE_RETURN><RESPONSE><DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME><CODE>2014</CODE><TEXT>Toomanyconcurrentlogin(s)</TEXT></RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>'
```

A second way I can come up with is this:

```
new_str = ''.join(my_str.split())
```

It says 'split my_str at white spaces and then join the pieces that result from this with no character in between'. The output of `print` is the same.

Hope this helps, but again, I am not aware if these are the best ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
k = "<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>"
k.replace(" ","")
'<SIMPLE_RETURN><RESPONSE><DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME><CODE>2014</CODE><TEXT>Toomanyconcurrentlogin(s)</TEXT></RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) regex function:

```
import re

string = "<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>"

result = re.sub(r'> +<', '><', a)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
import re
str = "<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>"

str = re.sub("\>\s+",">", str)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's fairly simple.
You just need to get a regex to match whitespace between the tags

```
str string = "<SIMPLE_RETURN>  <RESPONSE>    <DATETIME>2018-05-09T12:47:24Z</DATETIME>    <CODE>2014</CODE>    <TEXT>Too many concurrent login(s)</TEXT>  </RESPONSE></SIMPLE_RETURN>
" 
string = re.sub(r">(\s+)<","><",string)
```